# Prefix an inherited Makefile target

Tags: makefile

My project's Makefile includes another makefile to which we do not want to make local modifications.

From it, we inherit a target called `test`.
How can I edit my own Makefile, to ensure a custom command gets run **before** the inherited `make test` target?

I get around this now by defining a new `itest` target, but I'd rather just be able to call `make test`.

```
include: other-project/rules.mk

.PHONY: itest
itest:
    <my-command> $(MAKE) test
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a prerequisite:

```
include: other-project/rules.mk

test: itest

.PHONY: itest
itest:
    <my-command>
```